# copy search results of emeditor macro output to clipboard and send it to potplayer

Tags: emeditor

i am using the emeditor macro code ExtractLinesContain.jsee (downloaded from emeditor macro library) to search text file for certain text. this code is perfectly working. it is pasting the results to new file. but i want the result to be copied to clipboard and also should be sent to potplayer.
three modifications are required in the above code.

1. multiple texts are entered using separator '|'. i want to use ',' in place of '|'.
2. search results to be automatically copied to search results.
3. the following code to be appeneded to the above macro code.
   editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4445);
   WshShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );

WshShell.Run ( "PotPlayerMini64.exe /clipboard" );

please help me.

Comment: Where's the 'above code' you reference at the end of the first paragraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ExtractLinesMulti.jsee* macro is very old, and I rewrote the macro using the **Batch Find/Extract** feature of EmEditor instead. Here is the macro that extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by `|`:

```
if( !editor.EnableTab ){ 
   editor.EnableTab = true; 
   alert( "Please run this macro again." ); 
   Quit(); 
}

sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by |:", "" );
if( sFind == "" ){
    Quit();
}

var sArr = sFind.split("|");
batch_list = editor.filters;
for( i = 0; i < sArr.length; ++i ) {
    batch_list.AddFind(sArr[i],eeFindReplaceCase,0);
}
document.selection.BatchFind(batch_list, eeFindExtract | eeFindLineOnly,0);

document.selection.SelectAll();  // select all text
document.selection.Copy(eeCopyUnicode);  // copy the seleciton to the Clipboard
```

You can add any code you want to the end of this macro.

References: http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_selection_batch_find.html

Comment: the above code is not working.
using the above code i have searched for zeher|yogi
and i got the result in new file as
 ===== zeher =====
===== yogi =====

eventhough there are lines with zeher, yogi words or strings, but result turned nil.

how to copy the result to clipboard automatically?

Comment: my text is as follows D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 1.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 2.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 3.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 4.avi D:\Devadas\Yogi 1.MPG
D:\Devadas\Yogi 2.MPG
D:\Devadas\Yogi 3.MPG
D:\Devadas\Yogi 4.MPG

Comment: sir, i think your search code is case sensitive. how to make it case insensitive and results are shown as ===== Zeher =====
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 1.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 2.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 3.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 4.avi
===== Murder =====
D:\Devadas\New Songs1\Murder songs\Murder 1.mp4
D:\Devadas\New Songs1\Murder songs\Murder 2.mp4
D:\Devadas\New Songs1\Murder songs\Murder 3.mp4
D:\Devadas\New Songs1\Murder songs\Murder 4.mp4 i don't want to display ===== Zeher =====
===== Murder =====
lines in the result. how to omit them?

Comment: To do case insensitive search, replace eeFindReplaceCase with 0 in the above code. Please create separate questions for separate issues.

Comment: i have replaced eeFindReplaceCase with 0, but it is not able to show the results.

Comment: results are not getting copied to clipboard. can you please add clipboard code line also?

Comment: hello sir,
your old macro ExtractLinesMulti.jsee is suiting to my needs not your latest code. can you please add three modifications to the old macro code.

1.multiple texts are entered using separator '|'. i want to use ',' in place of '|'.
2.search results to be automatically copied to search results.
3.the following code to be appeneded to the above macro code. editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4445); WshShell = new ActiveXObject( "WScript.Shell" );
WshShell.Run ( "PotPlayerMini64.exe /clipboard" );

Comment: I added code to copy text to the Clipboard to my answer. Please create new questions for separate topics.

Comment: sir in your code the result is shown as ===== zeher =====
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 1.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 2.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 3.avi
D:\Devadas\Zehar\Zeher 4.avi
===== maro =====
D:\Devadas\sipayi\Ye Theega Poovuno Song __ Maro Charithra Movie Songs __ Kamal Haasan _ Saritha.mp4
D:\Devadas\new songs\Maro Charitra 1.mov
D:\Devadas\new songs\Maro Charitra 2.mov ,   i don't want the lines  ===== zeher =====

===== maro =====
 can you please guide me?

Comment: `Ctrl+F`, click **Batch >>**, click **▼** by **Batch Extract**, clear **Enable Separator**.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It is perfectly working. but my first requirement is multiple texts are entered using separator '|'. i want to use ',' in place of '|'.  It is not implemented in the code given by you.

Comment: Do you want to use `|` or `,`??? Please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to use ,

Comment: Then why did you mention `|` in your first question? You can just replace `"|"` with `","` in my code.

Comment: i could guess from your code  and modified it as sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by ,:", "" ); it is perfectly workings. Thanks a lot for helping me out patiently.  Now all my requirements are solved. thanks  a lot for the great help.
if( sFind == "" ){
    Quit();
}
var sArr = sFind.split(",");

Comment: Is it possible to increase font size to 20 and user window to multiple line size  in the code given . sFind = prompt( "This macro extracts lines that do contain any of the specified multiple strings separated by |:", "" );
if( sFind == "" ){
    Quit();
}  font size is appearing very small.